# Github pull request is marked as close but still open, any way to bypass?

Tags: github

1. [Branch is closed but treated as opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qf0x.png)
2. [PR is closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYUZo.png)

I would like to remove the `develop` branch but it has a PR open... but that PR is closed.

Right now I am unable to create a pull request `master` <- `develop`

Comment: Is there another PR still open on develop?

Comment: Can you delete the remote branch from local CLI?

Comment: @Schwern You're right, thanks! Unfortunately, even when I have successfully removed the branch but if I use the same name (`develop`) it is still stuck.

Comment: @user2233706 Yes but looks like deleting the branch doesnt work.

Comment: @Sam What happens when you try to make a PR of develop into master?

Comment: @Schwern Github will not allow to create a new PR and show me the link of my last PR: https://i.ibb.co/d7gDWdG/Screenshot-2021-05-27-at-11-26-58-AM.png

Comment: @Sam It says right there that master is up to date with develop. There's nothing to merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [your screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/d7gDWdG/Screenshot-2021-05-27-at-11-26-58-AM.png), GitHub isn't letting you make a PR to merge develop into master because there's nothing to merge. master is up to date with develop.

Did you remember to push your commits to develop?

Comment: Thanks! I think I might have misunderstood what happened with the PR!

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the branch from the cli using:

```
git push origin --delete develop
```

Comment: You're right, thanks! I was thinking if deleting the branch will work but it seems like it does not.

Comment: deleting the branch from the CLI just deletes your local branch :D